# Handling conflicts in SVN with Tortoise?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, conflict

Any time an issue comes up like a merge conflict or something similar, it really slows me down.

Can someone explain to me how to force-resolve conflicts?

For example, a buddy of mine made an edit to a file on the repository and committed.  While he was doing that, I had already renamed that file and made many edits to it on my working copy.

When I went to commit, I get the conflict error obviously.  The file he edited doesn't even exist anymore on my working copy.  How can I tell SVN to simply quit crying about the conflict and force it to accept my working copy (ie, overwrite the head revision with my working copy).

Comment: I found a video where resolve conflicts with Tortoise SVN is explained
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmARaN5eb3U

Answer (score 10):

When you update your working copy you can right-click in the log list and chose how to resolve the conflict:

- resolve using an editor / TortoiseMerge (or whatever merge tool you configured)
- resolve using "theirs", i.e. the version in the repository
- resolve using "mine", i.e. your version of the file.

This also works when deleting files *properly* -- i.e. you *need* to delete the file using svn if you want to actually delete it from the repository. If you removed the file for convenience reasons you might want to `svn revert` it before updating as a file missing from the working copy is a modified file too (unsurprisingly).

To sum it up: you **can't** tell svn to "stop crying" and simply overwrite with your working copy. This is a good thing. You need to resolve the conflict (which could mean simply overwriting the current state), mark the affected files as resolved (`svn resolved`) and then commit the result.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I did it:

1. Right click on the Solutions folder, click TortoiseSVN -> Show Log.
2. Right click the revision you want to revert, select "Revert Changes from this revision"
3. Right click the conflicted folders, select "Resolved".
4. Commit your solution
5. Profit

Comment: And your buddy does the same with your commit to fix his working copy? ;-)

I would suggest talking to your buddy, committing small logical changes and updating frequently.

Comment: What if I made changes and committed and the other user made changes and would like that change to merge with what I committed? I am having a little setback with that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to prevent this from happening is to Update before you Commit.

Comment: Well, it is happened and Updating Or Committing don't work until it is resolved.

Comment: Can we rollback his commit some how?

Comment: sometimes i have had to backup my work in a seperate folder, delete the repository and re-create my local repository/trunk from SVN Server. You can also try the "Clean Up" and "Resolved" functions, but those usually dont work too great. Just make sure you both have backed up your changes before wiping anything, so you do not lose work. In the future, it is best practice to Update right before you Commit. It can save these headaches.

Comment: you can rollback a commit by using "Show Log" from the menu. Here is a link from Tortoise on how: 

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html

Answer (score 1):

I would say: The best way to prevent this from happening is to Update before you...MODIFY the file. 
Once you are done with your changes you will lose them if you update before you commit!

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is:
If you're in two pane view, then you can only edit the file in the right pane (Mine). To apply changes made in the left file (Theirs), right click on the changed lines and select Context Menu → Use text block from 'theirs' . Then the changes from the left file are added to the right file.

Sometimes you actually want both text blocks, and the context menu also offers you Context Menu → Use both text blocks (this one first) and Context Menu → Use both text blocks (this one last).

If you're in three pane view (sometimes called merge view) you can only edit the file in the bottom view (Merged). As in two pane view, you can right click on conflicted lines and either select Context Menu → Use text block from 'theirs' or Context Menu → Use text block from 'mine' . In addition, if you want both blocks, you can select Context Menu → Use text block from 'mine' before 'theirs' or Context Menu → Use text block from 'theirs' before 'mine' . According to the command you've selected, the changes are used in the resulting Merged file.

Referenced link : https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseMerge_en/tmerge-dug-conflicts.html