# Subversion says my file "remains in conflict"

Tags: c#, .net, svn, tortoisesvn, csproj

I'm trying to commit a *.csproj file using Tortoise SVN, but get:

**Commit Failed!
...Aborting commit.... .csproj remains in conflict.**

OK, so how do I determine what the conflict is so that I can hopefully resolve it?

Comment: http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=178

Comment: Was you csproj in conflict before commit? Because error message to missed update of WC seems differently

Comment: It seems I need to open the solution in Visual Studio via File | Subversion | Open from Subversion... as opposed to File | Recent Projects and Solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVN remains in conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406469/svn-remains-in-conflict)

Comment: @2240: This question is almost 11 years old, and I've been retired for some years now; I remember nothing about it, sorry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use TortoiseSVN to `TortoiseSVN->Check for modifications`

Any conflicts will be highlighted here, and can be edited with `TortoiseSVN->Edit Conflicts`.  You could use TortoiseMerge (comes with TortoiseSVN) to resolve your conflicts.

Finally, you can use the command `TortoiseSVN->Resolved` to remove the temporary riles (e.g. *.mine) that were created by the conflict.

Now you are safe to `TortoiseSVN->Commit` your changes.

Comment: re: "Check for Modifications": Yes, I've tried that, and it gives me a list of files, some red, some blue, some black.

But what do I do with that? It doesn't give me an option, that I can see, to get any modified files...

Comment: I guess I responded too quickly. I'll try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the TortoiseSVN site: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html

Also have a look at these questions:

- [Handling conflicts in SVN with Tortoise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065916/handling-conflicts-in-svn-with-tortoise)
- [Tortoise SVN conflict occurs but no edit conflict button is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440721/tortoise-svn-conflict-occurs-but-no-edit-conflict-button-is-shown)
- [Tortoise SVN tree conflict with myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951078/tortoise-svn-tree-conflict-with-myself)